# wrapping even number of boxes bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have 4 boxes and I'm trying to set even spaces between them.
The boxes are arranged dependent on the screen size:

1. if its `xxl`+ then the 4 boxes are arranged in one horizontal line(row).
2. else, if it's `md`+ then two boxes in the first row and the other two in the another row.
3. otherwise, each one in a row.

I have this code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid p-0 d-md-flex justify-content-md-evenly flex-md-wrap">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code gets 1. and 3. done (but not 2. as at a certain point a single box get wrapped alone).
I can fix this and get 2. and 3. by wrapping first two boxes together in a div and last two together in other div, but then I can't achieve 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll accept a CSS alternative solution consider these:

Using `Flexbox`:

```css
.custom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.example {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .custom {
    gap: 0;
  }
  .example {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="custom">
  <div class="example">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
      <p>some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
      <p>some content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="example">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
      <p>some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
      <p>some content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I did here is make use of `flexbox` and `@media` queries to achieve the same effect as bootstrap does. `md` in bootstrap is `>=768px` if I remember correctly so setting `max-width: 768px` on screen size would do the trick.

If you want to learn `flexbox` click [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). For media queries, more on it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp).

Using `grid` and 2 `@media` queries:

```css
.custom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .custom {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .custom {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="custom">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I did on this one is using `flexbox` for the number1 and 3 effect. And converts to `grid` when screen-size is `1200px`. `grid` let's you customize 2 dimensions at once, so it's much easier to use it to achieve the 2nd effect you were looking for.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, it was one of my attempts to solve it, but as you can see on full screen (when the 4 boxes arranged in one line) the space between the second and the third box is bigger than the spaces between other boxes. 
that's simple because you are first splitting the line between the two pair of boxes and then placing equal space between them, the space between the two pair will be double the space between each box in the pair

Comment: @user2401856 If `justifying-content` can be `center`ed then I have the behavior that you want on my edit. Tell me if it's enough.

Comment: Also added a different method with `grid` in adjustment to your edits.

Answer (score 0):

Restructuring markup will help you to achieve the desired layout!

```css
.example {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .example {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items:center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid p-0 d-xxl-flex justify-content-xxl-evenly">
  <div class="example">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
      <p>some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
      <p>some content</p>
    </div>


    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
      <p>some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
      <p>some content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `2. else, if it's md+ then two boxes in the first row and the other two in the another row.`
you didn't refer to this, the boxes never appear as one pair in first row and last pair in second row.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, it mainly depended on the `display: contents` attribute, which gives the solution along with this idea

> I can fix this and get 2. and 3. by wrapping first two boxes together in a div and last two together in other div, but then I can't achieve 1.

I wasn't able to achieve 1. because on `xxl`+ screen, the `justify-content-xxl-evenly` attribute of the outer `div.container` is being applied on the wrapping `divs` of each pair and not on the content itself.
wrapping first pair and last pair with

```
display: contents on xxl+ screen
```

solves the problem, because `display: contents` unwraps the inner content of the element and passes it to the parent element.

Here's my edits to the final solution:

```css
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
.d-xxl-contents{
    display: contents !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid d-xxl-flex justify-content-xxl-evenly">
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column align-items-center flex-md-row justify-content-md-evenly d-xxl-contents">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
            <p>some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
            <p>some content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column align-items-center flex-md-row justify-content-md-evenly d-xxl-contents">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
            <p>some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
            <p>some content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyway, I strongly believe that there's a better solution, especially that this solution will be very long when generalized on multiple boxes.
will be happy if anyone posts a lighter one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you are using fixed width to your columns. For good responsive behavior set width in percentage and use max-width property.

Here is a simple solution without using @media queries. I have only used the bootstrap breakpoints.

```css
.box{
    width: 90%; 
    max-width: 350px;
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: coral;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row px-0">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xxl-3 border" ><p class="box" >some content</p></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xxl-3 border" ><p class="box" >some content</p></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xxl-3 border" ><p class="box" >some content</p></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xxl-3 border" ><p class="box" >some content</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```